# procedure or function to insert if row does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a function or procedure that checks if a row exists and returns the row id; otherwise it creates a row and returns that row id. Here is what I have:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `is_school`//
CREATE FUNCTION is_school (school_name VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNS INT unsigned 
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    BEGIN
        DECLARE school_id INT unsigned;
        SELECT `id` INTO school_id FROM `schools` WHERE `name`=school_name LIMIT 1;
        IF school_id = NULL THEN
            INSERT INTO `schools` (`name`) VALUES (school_name);
            RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();
        ELSE
            RETURN school_id;
        END IF;
    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

It works fine if the row exists. But it doesn't seem to want to execute that insert statement. If you try to call the function on a new school, it does not create that school. I've also tried writing this as a procedure with the OUT param. Any thoughts on where I am going wrong?

Comment: E.g., select is_school("University of Texas, Austin"); returns a value. select is_school("Brand new school not in DB"); returns null.

Comment: what's the value in `school_id`

Comment: @maSTAShuFu it's initially null when declared, then it gets assigned a value in the select statement or remains null. When it remains null, it is supposed to insert a new school into the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
IF school_id = NULL THEN
```

with

```
IF school_id IS NULL THEN
```

.

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html):

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL.